# Bash not recognizing aliases when run from Vim

Tags: external-command, bash

In Vim, when I run this command `:!bash -c "ll"`, I get this error message `bash: ll: command not found`. `ll` is an alias in my ~/.bashrc file. If I just enter `ll` from bash it works. I created a ~/.bash_profile file and added the following to it:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I looked at my ~/.profile file and saw that it already had this at the beginning:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

I even tried setting bash to run in interactive mode, and it still won't recognize my aliases. If I use `ls` instead of `ll`, it works fine, since `ls` is not a custom alias.

Comment: The simplest solution is to add `-i` to the `shellcmdflag` setting, e.g. `:set shellcmdflag=-ic`. This makes sure the spawned shell is an interactive shell which reads your aliases.

Answer (score 11):

Your issue is with bash and not with vim. The problem is that when you run `!<cmd>` in vim or `/bin/bash -c <cmd>` from another shell you are launching an instance of bash in non-interactive mode. In non-interactive mode alias are not expanded and you get this error. I don't know if you'd be able to enable the shell option `expand_aliases` from these types of situations since you're back into a non-interactive shell when you invoke `!`.

If you try to start an interactive shell it will put the vim process in the background after your command executes.

```
!/bin/bash -i -c ll
```

Comment: How can the blame be put on bash :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a strategy I use for this that utilizes the `BASH_ENV` which you can read about in `man bash` (and below). This strategy focuses specifically on what I want made available in vim.

```
When  bash  is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example,
it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it
appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and
execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:

if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
```

So, in your vimrc, you can do something like:

`let $BASH_ENV="~/.vim/vim_bash"`

In `vim_bash` you have content like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
shopt -s expand_aliases  
alias ll='ls -la'
alias foo='bar'
alias you='get the idea'
```

And that's really all there is to it. Now in vim you can do `!ll`

If you really did want to use your entire `.bashrc` you'd have to make sure you add `shopt -s expand_aliases` in it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of different plugins for that. For example, [vim-run-interactive](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-run-interactive).

But today you can also use `:help :terminal`. Or use `GNU Screen` or `tmux`. Or just split windows in your terminal emulator.