# How to use WSL's bash shell as default terminal of gvim/windows 10?

Tags: gvim, terminal, microsoft-windows

gvim 8 1-26 / windows 10

I'd like to use Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL)'s bash shell as a gvim's terminal instead of `cmd`.

So if I type in command potion of gvim: `:!.\test.sh`, it will echo result inside of gvim terminal - wsl's bash shell (not open a `cmd` window, login to bash, and then run `test.sh`).

Expected result would be similar to run vim inside a terminal in a linux distribution (for i.e `vim` under `urxvt-unicode`)

Answer (score 9):

GVim is a 32-bit application and WSL must run on 64 bit. On Windows 10 you can use GVim with WSL if you add the following to your vimrc file:

```
if has("win32")
    set shell=C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe
    set shellpipe=|
    set shellredir=>
    set shellcmdflag=
endif
```

Comment: This is golden answer, now cmd window won't pop-up each time I run a shell command. I have two questions: 1. it's a bit slow to complete the command - can we speed it up? 2. I try some plugins that would use .exe for stuff for i.e: tagbar plugin, echo error when try to invoke .exe file on window, obviously because we're redirecting to another shell `wsl.exe`, then I try to install `ctags ver5.9` on `wsl`, manually tags a file under wsl: `> ctags myfile.py`. Back to gvim/windows toggle Tagbar gave no tags found.

Comment: Came across this from searching around. Thank you for this helpful answer. However, if I'm not wrong, `has('windows')` checks if vim is compiled with support for multiple windows, and not the OS it is running on. Instead of `has('windows')`, one should use `has('win32')` or `has('win64')`.

Comment: @husB Indeed, my mistake. should be has('win32') or has('win64'). Thanks for your feedback! I'll update the example (and even my vimrc file)

Comment: When I do this on gvim 8.2 and WSL 2 Ubuntu I get an error:
E485: Can't read file C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\VJB4EFA.tmp

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this simply by assigning to the `'shell'` setting the path of whatever Bash binary you are using.

I have a similar setup with Gvim + Cygwin and this is what I have in my `_vimrc` file...

```
set shell=c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe
```

You may need to add a bit extra if the bare shell launched by the above has, let's say, an empty PATH environment variable. For example, you could specify a bash init file like this...

```
set shell='c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --rcfile /foo/bar/mybashrc'
```

...and define PATH in `mybashrc`.

There's [an earlier answer of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16193/11054) that touches upon a somewhat related topic that you can read if you need more help choosing the correct bash parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After some frustrating years of trying to get gvim and WSL/ubuntu to play together I finally read through the vim documentation and figured out why it has been failing for me. The issue was the [shellquote](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shellquote%27) and shellxquote settings, by default it was wrapping my command with parentheses and I would get an error like "E485: Can't read file C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\VJB4EFA.tmp".

Here are the settings that finally allowed this to work for me:

```
if has("win32") || has("win64")
    set shell=bash.exe
    set shellslash
    set shellpipe=|
    set shellredir=>
    set shellquote=\"
    set shellxquote=
    set shellcmdflag=-c
endif
```