# Change Vim command :terminal so instead of CMD there will open Bash terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

I am used working on Vim on Linux, where I use tmux + vim to switch between terminal and vim edit quickly. Now I am trying to setup the same on windows 10.

I try to use gVim on Windows 10, but I like to work in Bash terminal. Windows 10 allows you to download and used it Microsoft Bash terminal. 
Problem that I have now, is to change in gVim default cmd terminal to Bash terminal, by typing in gVim command `:terminal`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could change the option `shell`, see `:help :terminal` and `:help 'shell'`. But this means, that you also use `shell` for all `:!` commands. I don't know if you want that.

On the other hand, you could just define a new command:

```
command Bash  terminal ++close bash
```

The `++close` is needed, so Vim closes the terminal window when you exit bash.

Comment: I tryed your command `command Bash  terminal ++close bash` but I get error CreateProcess fail. Right now I am using gVim on Win10, and I thought that I must change or add a path where I got my bash terminal installed. (As I look up it is in WindowsApps). Right now when I type `:terminal` gVim split windows and opens cmd. I just want to somehow open bash.

Comment: You should replace `bash` with the full path of your bash executable, like `C:/.../bash.exe`.

Comment: Sorry, was a bad idea to answer a Windows10 question as a Linux guy. You could also check for `wsl.exe` or `ubuntu.exe`. If this doesn't work, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: could that be a 32bit vs. 64bit issue?

Comment: If I type in my gVim this command: `:terminal C:\path\to\wsl.exe`, gVim will split window at start, set a blinking courser at the first location and everything else will be empty. Not even standard bash output `myname@116000375IE:/mnt/c/$`. But when I try to type something in it immediately closes.

Comment: Or if you try ubuntu.exe you will get:   `Error: 0x80070005
Press any key to continue...`

Comment: Just realized that it might be a duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16386/how-to-use-wsls-bash-shell-as-default-terminal-of-gvim-windows-10