# Is it possible to change the default terminal of Vim?

Tags: terminal

I'd like to change the default terminal of Vim from `cmd` to `cmder`. By using `:help :terminal` I have read the `terminal.txt` but it seems that there is no setting instruction in that help file.

So is it likely to change the default terminal of vim by using `:terminal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [help for `:terminal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal) says:

> If [command] is not given the 'shell' option is used.

On that help page, if you move the cursor inside the word "shell" and press `C-]` (the control key and the right bracket), it'll take you to the help for the shell setting.  Alternatively, you can get there with `:help 'shell'`.

It looks like you should be able to add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
set shell=cmder
```

You may need to specify the full path to cmder depending on whether it's in your system path.

Also note that the `shell` setting is used for executing external commands from vim.  I'd recommend reading the help for that setting to make sure it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, it works after I set the path to cmder.exe. However the Cmder window pops up instead of staying inside the gvim window as expected when I use `:terminal `.

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Cmder's-shell-in-other-terminals.  You may be able to adapt this to make it integrate with vim better.

Unfortunately, I'm not particularly familiar with cmder, but it appears to be more of a terminal emulator rather than a shell, so that may have something to do with it.  This link explains the difference better than I can: https://askubuntu.com/questions/506510/what-is-the-difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line

Comment: Thanks.`:help terminal` tells me that the vim terminal is actually also a emulator so it's silly to run a terminal emulator in another terminal emulator. So I just change the default shell to the WSL bash following the setup from https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16386/how-to-use-wsls-bash-shell-as-default-terminal-of-gvim-windows-10.

Comment: What's the answer for Neovim?