# Unable to set WSL as the shell on gVim

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell

I followed the instructions given in this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16436/25843, and I've set my shell to point to wsl.exe like this (wsl.exe path seems to be different on my machine compared to the linked answer):

```
if has("windows")
    set shell=C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
    set shellpipe=|
    set shellredir=>
    set shellcmdflag=
endif
```

But I end up getting this error if I try to run, let's say `:!ls`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe  "ls"
'C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

However, directly running `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe  "ls"` in the command line seems to work. Also, setting the shell to point to the PowerShell executable seems to work as well, so I'm confused about what I am missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, my bad. Turns out the path should really be `C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe`, as mentioned in the linked question. I changed it to `System32` because I couldn't find the `Sysnative` folder under `C:\Windows`.

Apparently the `Sysnative` folder is kind of a virtual folder which exists only from the perspective of 32-bit programs.

More info can be found here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1598
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications