# How to use bash aliases in ftplugin files?

Tags: bash, filetype-c++, makeprg, ft-plugin

I want to be able to compile and run C++ files directly from inside vim. I have a custom compilation alias `gmm` defined in `~/.bash_aliases`. I do not want to copy it over to my `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim` file as it is quite a big command (several warning flags and stuff).

If I use the following I get an error:

```
nnoremap <F4> :w<CR>:vs \| te gmm % && ./a.out < in<CR>i
inoremap <F4> <esc>:w<CR>:vs \| te gmm % && ./a.out < in<CR>i
```

since vim cannot find the `gmm` alias. Is there any way to make the alias available to the `cpp.vim` file?

Comment: Have you tried something like `:term bash -ilc gmm`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt If i execute it inside vim, it says "Command gmm not found. Did you mean..."

Comment: I think you need to configure the `$BASH_ENV` variable, e.g `let $BASH_ENV = "$HOME/.bash_aliases"`

Comment: @Biggybi Okay, I put `let $BASH_ENV = "$HOME/.bash_aliases` in my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file. Even then, if I run `:term bash -ilc gmm` it says command gmm not found.

Comment: Are you running gvim or vim in the terminal?

Comment: @Biggybi Sorry for not clarifying earlier. I am using neovim v0.4.3, in the terminal, in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Welcome to this site Gauran! :) I feel like this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2950/1841) because the solution will probably be the same. Also if you want to do this kind of compilation I strongly recommend that you take a look at [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27) to do it the right way :)

Comment: My recommendation: **Don't** use aliases. If something is worth calling from an external application such as vim, then it's worth turning it into its own standalone script. Only use aliases (or, better, functions!) for things that *really* need to be one, because they change the current shell directory or set variables in the current environment, etc. For everything else, standalone scripts are much superior.

Comment: @GaurangTandon if you start bash as an intractive login shell (`-il`)  it should read your alias file. So then the command should work. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you statox and @filbranden ! I setup `gmm` a custom bash script, added it to path, and setup `makeprg` and now it works perfectly!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you for your reply. I had tried `:term bash -ilc gmm` and it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: @GaurangTandon it's more a shell related question however. You need to make sure, that the shell reads your aliases.